# Freezing things like Fettuccine Alfredo

Tags: sauce, freezing, cream, alfredo

I don't have a lot of time to cook during the week, sadly, so I've been taking things like this for lunch http://www.eatyourbest.com/sitecore/content/Home/products/classic-favorites/fettucini-alfredo.aspx . It's simple and tasty, but I would prefer to make things like this at home on the weekends and freeze it for a later date.

I know freezing a cream sauce can be kind of complicated/impossible, so if I were to try and freeze some portioned home-made Fettuccine Alfredo what are some things I need to do to help it come out of the microwave and not be awful?

Edit: I wasn't 100% specific in my query originally - I also want to prevent as much damage as possible to the sauce, since I know milk based products don't always freeze very well. Will the reheating process be affected by any damage to the sauce, or would the steps I take to ensure the sauce doesn't separate during reheating also protect it from freezer damage?

Comment: The problem with an alfredo sauce isn't in the freezing, it's in the re-heating: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8775/how-can-i-reheat-a-roux-based-alfredo-sauce-in-the-microwave-without-separatio.

Comment: Thank you, that's a fantastic correlary to what I'm trying to accomplish. I will def. keep that in mind while trying all this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to freeze something is to do it **fast**.  Chill the food first in the refrigerator before putting it in the freezer.  Keeping the food thin/flat rather than thick will help the center to chill faster. Loading up a sheet pan with individual portions works well for this - just be sure you have room for it in the refrigerator and freezer.

However, the larger problem with this type of sauce is re-heating of it - the sauce tends to split into its constituent ingredients.  Reheating the sauce very slowly on low heat is the best way to prevent the splitting.  You can also consider adding some lecithin to the sauce during cooking, which will help stabilize it.  See [How can I reheat a roux-based (alfredo) sauce in the microwave without separation?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8775/how-can-i-reheat-a-roux-based-alfredo-sauce-in-the-microwave-without-separatio) and [Keeping A Sauce From Separating](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7853/keeping-a-sauce-from-separating) for details.