# emulisified sauces

Tags: emulsion

I make home made buffalo and bbq sauces and I am finding they separate....I want to bottle for family in baskets but don't like them separating in the canning jars.
If I switch to clarified butter or a liquid butter alternative will this help?
If so what is the ratio difference as I don't want my sauces too solid/liquid?
(ingredient eg: hot sauce, equal butter, vinegar and some spices....
Thanks,
T

Answer (score 3):

Butter is by no means a required ingredient in sauces like these; the simplest thing to do might be just to come up with a recipe that doesn't have butter/oil. But assuming that's the flavor you want...

No, switching types of butter is unlikely to help, unless you happen to find one that already contains some additional emulsifiers. As you say, you're trying to make an emulsified sauce, with water and oil, so you're going to need an an emulsifier. Egg yolk, honey, and mustard are probably the common everyday ingredient ones, but you can also buy lecithin, so you won't have to worry about changing the flavor of your sauces. See [this question for plenty more](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7853/keeping-a-sauce-from-separating).

Finally, an obligatory food safety note: it's best to use recipes from authoritative sources as starting points when you're canning/bottling. You can tweak spices and such from there, but if for example you're using less vinegar, making a less acidic sauce, it may not be safe anymore without pressure canning.